# Selenium Grid how to invoke Batch file or Jar file on Node machine from hub

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file, grid

Selenium Grid how to invoke Batch file or Jar file on Node machine using selenium grid code from the hub.

I have tried a couple of options but it does not execute on node instead it does not identify the path of the file to be executed on Node.

1. `String path="java -jar C:\\workspace\\javaFile.jar"; 
   Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);`
2. Keeping .bat file on node m/c
   `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\BatchExecution.bat");`
3. Keeping .bat file on node m/c 
   `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"C://BatchExecution.bat\"");
   p.waitFor();`